# sql server- How to browse a sql server database

Tags: php, sql-server

I've a windows webhost and it has a sql server in it .

I want to connect to this database and browse the data inside it , How can I do so ? Like the way we do in phpmyadmin and see the data in side it .

I want to get the data from this database via php and use these data, how can I do so ?

Comment: are you looking for a web based sql-server management?

Comment: check all instanse via `sqlcmd -L` and connect with `SSMS`

Comment: @FLICKER yes, is there anything available ?

Comment: you can find couple of them if you google it. see my answer

Answer (score 3):

Here are some steps that you could try :

> -install SQL server Management studio (or download it from microsoft for free)
>
> -if you have installed it, then open the software
>
> -After you open, it will asked you which server you want to join and ask you username and password
>
> -After finished logging in, then you can browse your data inside

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this

[SQL Server management](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1311/web-based-database-administration-for-sql-server/)